# No Foreground Window Shadow in Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur, ui

I recently updated my MacBook Pro from MacOS Catalina to BigSur (11.6). Suddenly, any window that is in focus loses its shadow. This makes it extremely difficult to  distinguish it from  adjacent windows. See my screenshot below. I cannot actually convince myself that this is normal behaviour, i.e. the way Apple intended it. Is there something wrong with my preferences?
[image]
Note that this problem occurs only in light mode. In dark mode, the window in focus still has a shadow - and even a border - around it and looks fine (see below).
[image]

Comment: what if you create a new (temporary) user and log in as that user, is it still the same?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For a new user, the window in focus does have a shadow and border around it. So there's definitely something wrong with my configuration. The question now is, how do I reset it back to default?

Comment: OK, so this is stranger than fiction. I created the new user, logged in as that user to verify what @SteveChambers suggested, then logged back in as the old user. Suddenly the problem is fixed - the window in focus has a border and shadow as one would expect.